# Seafaring and coastal deployments

Tags: small-world

Tonight we have seafaring skeletons who controlled the north sea on the 5 player board. There are 6 regions that are coastal. In normal play you can enter a new race from the coast. Does the seafarers prevent access to these regions?

Answer (score 6):

No, players can still deploy into lands adjacent to the sea whether the sea is occupied or not. From [the rules](https://ncdn1.daysofwonder.com/smallworld/en/img/sw_rules_2015_en.pdf):

> First Conquest
>
> > A player's race deploying on the map for the first time must enter it by conquering one of its border Regions (i.e. a Region adjacent to the edge of the board or one whose shore is on a Sea adjacent to the edge of the board, **even if the sea is occupied by a Seafaring Race**).